# Crystal reports -error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

tengo un problema con Visual basic, hice un sistema con sql server , esto lo hice en mi casa , pero cuando lo llevo a otra pc , me sale este error y no me muestra el reporte , pero en mi pc si me lo muestra 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda!!

Answer (score 0):

El error es claro, la conexión a la base de datos del reporte de Crystal Reports (.rpt) es incorrecta. Deberás editar el reporte, buscar en sus propiedades la cadena de conexión a la base de datos de SQL Server y cambiarla por el nuevo servidor.

Si el caso es que en el otro PC quieres que siga conectado a la base de datos original (la de tu PC), el problema es de conectividad: el nuevo PC no reconoce el nombre del tuyo -en este caso cambia el nombre de tu PC en la conexión por tu IP- o bien no tienes el puerto 1433 abierto en tu PC, o ambas cosas.
Pueden haber otros problemas, por ejemplo si utilizas la versión SQL Server Express, no tiene el puerto asignado por defecto y hay que ponerlo manualmente en el Configurador de SQL Server (Configuración de red-Protocolos-TCP/IP) y  activarlo. En el cliente nativo de SQL - TCP_IP poner 1433 en el puerto por defecto.